# Having bootable docker image in google cloud via terraform

Tags: docker, google-kubernetes-engine, terraform

I am trying to use terraform to build an instance group using my docker container. Is it possible to use a docker image as a source?

```
resource "google_compute_image" "bootable-image" {
  name = "my-custom-image"
  project = "my-test-compute-4803e3ad"
  source_disk = "gcr.io/my-test-compute-4803e3ad/hello"
}
```

I can not use kubernetes for other reasons.

Comment: this is disk image, not docker image.

Comment: Do you know what resource is needed for the "Deploy a container image to this VM instance." option available in the GUI?

Comment: Terraform is care of infrastructure, such as vpc, database,  more than applications (containers are belong to applications)  If need to manage containers in google cloud, maybe you can start with terraform's kubernetes provider (https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/kubernetes/index.html) and `kubernetes_pod` will manage the pod (which is container in docker)

Comment: I can not use kubernetes for technical reasons. I found the issue, the option is still in beta, this is the command line version

`gcloud compute instance-templates create-with-container template-name gcr.io/containername/hello:tag --tags http-server`